Automatically Select the option with the longest length in a dropdown
I want this combo selection box to automatically highlight the longest option in the list.
foreach($onedriveaccount in $onedriveaccounts)
{
  $comboBox1.Items.add($onedriveaccount)
  # This loop should set the item with the longest length to $defaultcomboselect but it doesn't seem to actually pick it
  if($onedriveaccount.length -gt $defaultcombobiglen)
    {
    $defaultcomboselect=$comboBox1.items.Count
    $defaultcombobiglen=$onedriveaccount.length
    }
}

$comboBox1.SelectedItem=$defaultcomboselect
$Form1.Controls.Add($comboBox1)

I want this to automatically select the longest option. This was the first issue in Automatically Select the option with the longest length in a dropdown and choose that option after 30 seconds

Assigning to .SelectedItem is correct there however you're assigning an integer ($comboBox1.items.Count) instead of the actual item. If you want to make it really simple, first add the items:
foreach ($onedriveaccount in $onedriveaccounts) {
    $comboBox1.Items.Add($onedriveaccount)
}

And then use the .Items Property to sort them by Length and pick the last item and make the assignment:
$comboBox1.SelectedItem = $comboBox1.Items | Sort-Object Length | Select-Object -Last 1

And, if you want all items in the ComboBox to display sorted by Length (longest item first) you could instead:
$onedriveaccounts | Sort-Object Length -Descending | ForEach-Object {
    $comboBox1.Items.Add($_)
}

And then assign the first item by indexing:
$comboBox1.SelectedItem = $comboBox1.Items[0]


isn''t $comboBox1.SelectedItem a INT index?

@sirtao no.....
